# why cache doesn't work as it supposed to be?

Tags: c, linux, performance, caching, cpu

According to http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/, while trying Example 2, time should drop until the offset equals to the cache line zie.
However, on my machine, it doesn't work.
The code is just like following.

```
#define SIZE 1024*1024*64

int main()
{
struct timeval start, end;
int k;
int i;

for(k = 1; k <= 1024; k *= 2)
{

    int *arr = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i += k)
        arr[i] *= 3;
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    printf("K = %d, time = %d\n", k,
            (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)*1000000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec));

    free(arr);
}
return 0;
}
```

The result comes out as:

K = 1, time = 410278
K = 2, time = 265313
K = 4, time = 201540
K = 8, time = 169800
K = 16, time = 155123
K = 32, time = 142496
K = 64, time = 137967
K = 128, time = 135818
K = 256, time = 135128
K = 512, time = 135167
K = 1024, time = 135462

Comment: Try `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`. And how big is `SIZE`?

Comment: And also, move the `malloc()` outside of the loop.

Comment: I have update the edit with the complete codes. malloc is not included in the time measurement. And I think if it use the same memory, the cache may reserved in memory. Then the test will not be accurate.

Comment: Actually, believe it or not, it can matter even if the `malloc()` is not inside the timed region. This is because of lazy allocation. That's why I asked you to try `calloc()` instead, and to move it outside both loops.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're multiplying garbage times 3.

Comment: And why do you say it's not working?

Comment: And if you're worried about bringing the array into cache, just stream a separate array a couple of times. That will kick your test array out of cache.

Comment: You should alloc the new array before you free the old one.

Comment: How did you compile your code? With *which compiler and optimizations* ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon the *compiler* (its version), the *optimization levels*, and the CPU. Apparently, most of the time is spent in `malloc` so I moved it out of the loop and increased `SIZE`.

I'm trying on Debian/Sid with GCC 4.8.1 on a i3770K processor with 16Gbytes of RAM.

with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 1024*1024*1024

int main ()
{
  struct timeval start, end;
  clock_t startcl, endcl;
  int k, i;

  int *arr = (int *) malloc (SIZE * sizeof (int));
  if (!arr) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
  for (k = 1; k <= 1024; k *= 2)  {
      gettimeofday (&start, NULL);
      startcl = clock();
      for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i += k)
        arr[i] *= 3;
      gettimeofday (&end, NULL);
      endcl = clock();
      printf ("K = %d, time = %ld, cpu clock=%ld microsec\n", k,
              (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 
              + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec),
              (long) (endcl - startcl));
    }
  free (arr);
  return 0;
}
```

and compiling with `gcc -Wall -mtune=native -O3 ./wilsonwen.c -o ./wilsonwen-O3` then running it:

> ```
> K = 1, time = 696074, cpu clock=680000 microsec
> K = 2, time = 361173, cpu clock=360000 microsec
> K = 4, time = 341920, cpu clock=340000 microsec
> K = 8, time = 341767, cpu clock=340000 microsec
> K = 16, time = 342065, cpu clock=340000 microsec
> K = 32, time = 224502, cpu clock=230000 microsec
> K = 64, time = 119544, cpu clock=120000 microsec
> K = 128, time = 51089, cpu clock=50000 microsec
> K = 256, time = 26447, cpu clock=20000 microsec
> K = 512, time = 14104, cpu clock=20000 microsec
> K = 1024, time = 8385, cpu clock=10000 microsec
> ```

which is more consistent with the blog you mentioned. Moving the `malloc` out of the outer loop on `k` is really important (if you don't, you don't see the cache effect, apparently because `malloc` and the underlying `mmap` syscall is eating quite a lot of time).

I cannot explain why for `k=1` it takes more time (perhaps, because the `malloc`-ed memory is taken into RAM by page faults?). Even by adding a `for (i=0; i<SIZE/1024; i++) arr[i] = i;` loop to "pre-fetch the pages" before your `for (k` loop  the time  for `k=1` is still nearly twice as bigger than for `k=2` . We do see the plateau for `k=2` to `k=16` mentioned in Igor Ostrovsky's blog. Replacing `malloc` with `calloc` is not very significant. Using `clang` (3.2) instead of `gcc` (4.8) for compilation gives very similar timing results.

**Optimizing is very important**, by trying with `gcc -Wall -O0 ./wilsonwen.c -o ./wilsonwen-O0` and running that I don't see any plateau (which you'll see even with `-O1`). It is well known that `gcc` without any optimization flags spit quite poor machine code.

A general rule when benchmarking is to enable the compiler optimizations.

Comment: `k=1` is taking longer because it's the first time the memory is touched. So the lazy allocation is happening during `k=1`. Afterwards, it's all good.

Comment: malloc is not in the time measurement.SO I don't think moving malloc make differences.

Comment: @Mystical: No, because as I said adding a `for (i=0; i<SIZE/1024; i++) arr[i] = i;` before the measurement don't change the timing.

Comment: @wilsonwen Actually it does. There are a tons of things about memory allocation that will "leak" beyond the boundaries of the actual call to `malloc()`. I already mentioned lazy allocation. Then you don't know where the memory is coming from, it could already be in the cache if you recently used the same region...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  I try your codes and adding prefetch, ther results is much more consistent with the blog. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Mystical k=1 takes longer because lazy allocation as you both talk about. And I try adding <pre>for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) arr[i] = i;<code>, it's OK then. I think BasileStarynkevitch mistakes SIZE/1024.

Answer (score 0):

The same as mine.

Someone got the same result in the discussion under that article. And he said maybe it is  just the the real CPU time for arr[i] *= 3.

When K = 1 , it needs to run SIZE times. But when K = 2, it only needs to run SIZE/2 times.

So you could rewrite the code to run the same times despite whatever the K is. Then check whether it is the same. I just had this thought while typing. I will try this later. If you have tried , please add a comment.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define SIZE 64*1024*1024
int32_t arr [SIZE];
struct timespec ts;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
long i,j= 0;
long start;
long start_sec;
int count = 1;
int k = 0;

// init the arr;
for (i = 0; i< 64*1024*1024;++i){
    arr[i] = 0;
}

for (j = 1; j< 1025;){
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    start = ts.tv_nsec;
    start_sec = ts.tv_sec;
    for (i = 0, k = 0; i< 64*1024*1024; i++, k+=j){
        k = k & (SIZE -1);
        arr[k] *=3;
        arr[k] =1;
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    printf ("%d, %ld, %ld\n", count,(ts.tv_sec-start_sec)*1000000000+(ts.tv_nsec -start), j);
    count++;
    j *= 2;
}
return 0;
}
```

and the output is below:

```
1, 352236657, 1
2, 356920027, 2
3, 375986006, 4
4, 494875602, 8
5, 957796009, 16
6, 1397285233, 32
7, 1784398514, 64
8, 1070586859, 128
9, 1130548756, 256
10, 1169113810, 512
11, 1312605482, 1024
```

If I comment out the arr-init loop, it takes more time than K=2 when K=1.

And we can see that, the time just increases as the expectation(before K = 128). Because we alway have a loop of 64*1024*1024 times despite the K. Greater the K is, more time the cache line will flush.

Well, but I can't explain the decreasing from K = 64 to K = 128.

And @Mysticial talked about the lazy-malloc, so I also did a experiment with the original code in the article, but added the arr-init loop to avoid the lazy-malloc problem. The cost of K = 1 did decrease, but it is still greater than K=2's cost and closer to K=2's cost * 2 than original version. Data is below:

```
1, 212882204, 1
2, 111660951, 2
3, 67843457, 4
4, 62980310, 8
5, 62092973, 16
6, 42531407, 32
7, 27686909, 64
8, 9142755, 128
9, 4064936, 256
10, 2342842, 512
11, 1130305, 1024
```

So I think the reason of the decreasing from K = 1 to K = 2 and K=2 to K=4 is the decreasing of the number of iterations from SIZE to SIZE/2.

This is what I think, but I'm not sure.

======================================================

I complied the code with -Ox, the decreasing disappeared (but have to add the arr-init loop). Thanks to @Basile.
I will check the differences in the asm code later.

This is the differences between the asm code:

Without O1,

```
    movq    $0, -32(%rbp)
    jmp .L5
.L6:
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movl    arr(,%rax,4), %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    addl    %eax, %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edx, arr(,%rax,4)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rax, -32(%rbp)
.L5:
    cmpq    $67108863, -32(%rbp)
    jle .L6
```

And with O1,

```
    movl    $0, %eax 
.L3:
    movl    arr(,%rax,4), %ecx # ecx = a[i]
    leal    (%rcx,%rcx,2), %edx # edx = 3* rcx
    movl    %edx, arr(,%rax,4) # a[i] = edx
    addq    %rbx, %rax # rax += rbx
    cmpq    $67108863, %rax 
    jle .L3
```

And I change the asm code without O1 to this,

```
    movq    $0, -32(%rbp) 
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rbx
    jmp .L5
.L6:
    movl    arr(,%rax,4), %edx 
    movl    %edx, %ecx 
    addl    %ecx, %ecx 
    addl    %ecx, %edx 
    movl    %edx, arr(,%rax,4) 
    addq    %rbx, %rax
.L5:
    cmpq    $67108863, %rax 
    jle .L6
```

Then I get the result:

```
1, 64119476, 1
2, 63417463, 2
3, 63732534, 4
4, 66703562, 8
5, 65740635, 16
6, 47743618, 32
7, 28402013, 64
8, 9444894, 128
9, 4544371, 256
10, 2991025, 512
11, 1242882, 1024
```

It's almost just the same as the O1.
It seems that the movq -32(%rbp), %rax stuff costs too much. But I don't know why.

Maybe I'd better ask a new question about it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I compiled the code with different -O options. This phenomenon disappears if I add the arr-init loop from the code in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I updated my answer. Could you tell the reason? And on my computer with O1(Xubuntu 13.04, gcc 4.7.3), I didn't see the big decrease from K=1 to K=2 while you could see it on your computer.